# Динамическое добавление комментариев AJAX, yii2

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

Нужно сделать обычную простую форму с комментариями(имя, текст, кнопка отправить) с записью в базу данных и динамическим отображением на Ajax.

Нашел несколько вариантов http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/ajax/126-otpravka_soobwenij_pri_pomowi_ajax.html или же http://habrasorium.ru/php/624-prostaya-ajax-sistema-kommentariev.html Но все это не для Yii2. Пытаюсь сделать сам, но даже не понимаю как все склепать в кучу.

Сделал простой вариант(через форму и модель передаем информацию в контроллер и уж далее запись в БД. Но как вкрутить сюда Ajax вообще не понимаю. Может где-то мануал есть или подскажите как все сделать правильно.

Comment: Настройте yii так что бы контроллер отдавал и принимал JSON. Во вьюхе пишите форму которая будет делать HTTP запросы.

Answer (score 2):

Для примера сделаем возможность добавления новой Заметки в списке заметок без перезагрузки страницы.

## Контроллер

```php
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new Notes();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
    {
        $model = new Notes();
    }
    $searchModel = new NotesSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

## Шаблоны

**index.php**

```php
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\modules\notes\models\NotesSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Notes');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="notes-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form',[
        'model' => $model,
    ]) ?>

<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'notes']) ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'note:ntext',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

**_form.php**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\modules\notes\models\Notes */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<?php
    $this->registerJs(
        '$("document").ready(function(){
            $("#new_note").on("pjax:end", function() {
            $.pjax.reload({container:"#notes"});  //Reload GridView
        });
    });'
    );
?>

<div class="notes-form">
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'new_note']) ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['data-pjax' => true]]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'note')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>

</div>
```

## Результат

[image: Результат]

## Что мы сделали

В действии actionIndex добавили сохранение данных новой Заметки, если они пришли в запросе post:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
   {
     $model = new Notes();
   }
```

Обернули виджеты GridView и ActionForm в пиджак:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'notes']) ?>
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Добавили небольшой скрипт, обновляющий GridView после добавления новой записи:

```
<?php
$this->registerJs(
    '$("document").ready(function(){
        $("#new_note").on("pjax:end", function() {
        $.pjax.reload({container:"#notes"});  //Reload GridView
    });
});'
);
?>
```

[Источник](http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-primeryaem-pjax-na-activeform-i-gridview.html)